# Query the SO data explorer for questions with 4 close votes within a specific tag

Tags: database, t-sql, dataexplorer

I am trying to build a query that displays the ID's of questions with 4 close votes within a particular tag. I do not care about the date the question was posted all I want is just questions with 4 closed votes so I can do some moderation in my free time and go through them and possibly get some of them put on hold or closed.

[SO data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) has a menu on the right where you can see the available columns.

My specific problem is that I can't seem to find the correct table & column that stores the current close votes count.

I tried something like this but I am failing to get any results

```
select COUNT(PostId) from Votes where PostId = '19577105' and VoteTypeId = '6'
```

Any pointer in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Posts.ID
FROM 
  Posts
  INNER JOIN Votes ON Posts.ID = Votes.PostID
WHERE
  Posts.PostTypeID = 1
  AND Posts.Tags LIKE '%C#%'
  AND Votes.VoteTypeID = 6
GROUP BY
  Posts.ID
HAVING
COUNT(DISTINCT Votes.ID) > 4
```

This takes a while to run so could probably be optimized. The Tag filter could probably use full text search which may be faster if it is enabled.